# doubly Linked list iterator python

Tags: python

I am constructing a doubly linked list and I am struggling on construct a doubly linked list iterator method in **PYTHON**.

This is my code so far

```
class DoubleListNode:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.prev = None
        self.next= None

class ListIterator:
    def __init__(self):
        self._current = self.head

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.size == 0 :
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            item = self._current.data
            self._current=self._current.next
            return item

class DoublyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head= None
        self.tail= None
        self.size = 0

    def add(self,data):
        newnode= DoubleListNode(data)
        self.size+=1
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = newnode
            self.tail = self.head
        elif data < self.head.data: # before head
            newnode.next = self.head
            self.head.prev= newnode
            self.head= newnode
        elif data > self.tail.data: # at the end
            newnode.prev= self.tail
            self.tail.next= newnode
            self.tail=newnode
        else:
            curNode = self.head
            while curNode is not None and curNode.data < data:
                curNode=curNode.next            
            newnode.next= curNode
            newnode.prev=curNode.prev
            curNode.prev.next= newnode
            curNode.prev=newnode

    def remove(self,data):
        curNode=self.head
        while curNode is not None and curNode.data!= data:
            curNode= curNode.next
        if curNode is not None:
            self.size -= 1
            if curNode is self.head:
                self.head= curNode.next
            else:
                curNode.prev.next=curNode.next
            if curNode is self.tail:
                self.tail=curNode.prev
            else:
                curNode.next.prev=curNode.prev
```

When I run a test it said `TypeError: iteration over non-sequence`. Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: In `__init__` where is `self.head` coming from? And how do you iterate?

Comment: How are you creating your `ListIterator` object?  Something is definitely wrong there, since `self._current = self.head` will raise and `AttributeError` in `__init__()`.

Comment: I implemented a doubly linked list earlier

here is the code for doubly linked list class

class DoublyLinkedList:
    #init
    def __init__(self):
        self.head= None
        self.tail= None
        self.size = 0
in that class I have add remove len methods

Comment: Please help others to help you by posting the more completed code, starting with __init__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two important things to fix.

First, your `DoublyLinkedList` class doesn't have an `__iter__` method. You probably want to create one that returns a `ListIterator` instance. Perhaps you're trying to do this manually, but this would be the normal approach.

Second, you need to fix the code in your `ListIterator` to work properly. Currently your `__init__` method doesn't initialize things correctly, and your `next` method tries to access member variables like `size` that don't exist.

Here's an implementation that I think will work:

```
def ListIterator(object):
    def __init__(self, node):
        self.current = node

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.current is None:
            raise StopIteration()

        result = self.current.data
        self.current = self.current.next

        return result

class DoublyLinkedList(object):

    # all your current stuff, plus:

    def __iter__(self):
        return ListIterator(self.head)
```

As a side note, in your current code you're defining classes with no bases. This is fine in Python 3 (where `object` will be the base by default), but in Python 2 this will result in getting an "old-style" class. Old-style classes are deprecated, and you'll find that some language features won't work properly with them (though not any of the features involved in iteration, as far as I know). On the other hand, if you are already using Python 3 then you need to define a `__next__` method in the iterator class, rather than `next` (without the underscores).

Answer (score 4):

As posted, the code doesn't initialize (i.e. *self.head* isn't defined).

But overall, you are on the right track.   Take a look at [the source for Python's *collections.OrderedDict*](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/80d7545594ca/Lib/collections.py#l22) for a worked-out example of traversing a doubly linked list.

Here's a simplified example:

```
class Link:
    def __init__(self, value, prev=None, next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.prev = prev
        self.next = next

    def __iter__(self):
        here = self
        while here:
            yield here.value
            here = here.next

    def __reversed__(self):
        here = self
        while here:
            yield here.value
            here = here.prev

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Link('raymond')
    b = Link('rachel', prev=a);  a.next=b
    c = Link('matthew', prev=b); b.next=c

    print 'Forwards:'
    for name in a:
        print name
    print
    print 'Backwards:'
    for name in reversed(c):
        print name
```

Comment: The message ``TypeError: iteration over non-sequence`` means that Python cannot find an *\_\_iter\_\_* method for an object.  Also note that in Python 3, we use *\_\_next\_\_* instead of *next*.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for Doubly Linked List class.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.data = val
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.count = 0

    def insert(self, val):
        newNode = Node(val)
        if self.count == 0:
            self.head = newNode
            self.tail = newNode
        else:
            self.head.prev = newNode
            newNode.next = self.head
            self.head = newNode
        self.count += 1

    def insertToEnd(self, val):
        newNode = Node(val)
        if self.count == 0:
            self.head = newNode
            self.tail = newNode
        else:
            self.tail.next = newNode
            newNode.prev = self.tail
            self.tail = newNode
        self.count += 1

    def search(self, val):
        p = self.head
        while p is not None:
            if p.data == val:
                return p
            p = p.next

    def delete(self, val):
        curNode = self.head
        while curNode != None:
            if curNode.data == val:
                if curNode.prev != None:
                    curNode.prev.next = curNode.next
                else:
                    self.head = curNode.next

                if curNode.next != None:
                    curNode.next.prev = curNode.prev
                else:
                    self.tail = curNode.prev

                self.count -= 1

            curNode = curNode.next


    def show(self):
        s = ""
        p = self.head
        while p is not None:
            s += str(p.data) + ' ';
            p = p.next
        print(s + "| count: " + str(self.count))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you post, may I suggest:

```
class ListIterator:
    # other stuff ...
    def __iter__(self):
        while self._current:
            yield self._current.data
            self._current = self._current.next
        self._current = self.head # Reset the current pointer
```

You don't have to implement next()

#### Update

Here is an example usage:

```
for data in myListIterator:
    print data

# Without reset, the second time around won't work:
for data in myListIterator:
    print data
```