# Python Iterators on Linked List Elements

Tags: python, iterator

I apologize in advance if this question is misplaced or duplicate.

This question is similar in nature to [doubly Linked list iterator python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710895/doubly-linked-list-iterator-python).

However, unlike the referenced question, I don't wish to create a overarching linked list object which contains a lot of metadata and provides the iterator (they are not necessary for my application).

My question is: Is there any fundamental reason why I should not or can not provide an iterator that doesn't iterate over elements it contains, but instead jumps through distinct element objects that are linked to each other via references?

The iterator is not necessary for proper functioning of the code, but I rather like the syntactic sugar of the `for item in` construction.

My implementation looks a bit like this (simplified version):

```
class LinkedAccount:
    def __init__(self, someParameter, nextAccount = None, prevAccount = None):

        self.someParameter = someParameter

        self.next = nextAccount
        self.prev = prevAccount
        if nextAccount is not None:
            self._tell_next()
        if prevAccount is not None:
            self._tell_prev()

    def _tell_next(self):
        if self.next is not None:
            self.next._recv_next(self)

    def _recv_next(self,prevAccount):
        self.prev = prevAccount

    def _tell_prev(self):
        if self.prev is not None:
            self.prev._recv_prev(self)

    def _recv_prev(self,nextAccount):
        self.next = nextAccount


    def __iter__(self):
        return AccountIterator(self)

class AccountIterator:
    def __init__(self,Account):
        self.Account = Account

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.Account is None:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            curAccount = self.Account
            self.Account = self.Account.next
            return curAccount
```

The LinkedAccount object provides an iterator that iterates from one LinkedAccount to the next, using the .next parameter already stored in the LinkedAccount object.

This approach appears to work, but the python iterator documentation seems to assume that the iterator is going to walk through elements contained by the parent object. Are there any pitfalls that preclude me doing something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem with doing it this way.

Think of each `LinkedAccount` as not only a node in a collection, but also as a collection itself, which includes the nodes after it.

A linked list may be thought of as a node and possibly another linked list.

```
[1, [2, [3, [4]]]]
```

Indeed, this is the concept of list in languages like Lisp.

There is nothing, functionally or documentation-wise,  that precludes an iterator from returning the same type as the object that it was called on. Likewise, there is no prohibition on collections "containing" (or equivalently, pointing to) other collections, nested n-deep.

If you are okay with viewing your `LinkedAccount` like the list above, and this makes sense for the people using your code, you are probably okay.

Comment: The way I understood the question was that this isn't a list of collections, but that he's having an item in a collection return the iterator that iterates over the collection. So in Lisp terms it would be like trying to make it so that you're writing code that semantically means iterating over the `car` of a list but actually iterates over the list itself.

Comment: Thank you for the well written and direct response to the question re: potential technical problems with such an implementation!

Comment: @ChadMiller, the `car` doesn't have a pointer to the next item, but `LinkedAccount` *does* have a pointer to the next item. Thus in this analogy `LinkedAccount` is the `cons`, and `LinkedAccount.someParemeter` is the `car`.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like it would work but it is semantically weird for the exact reason you mentioned. Having the `__iter__` defined on `LinkedAccount` makes it sound like you're iterating over the account itself and not a list of accounts. What you have now makes it seem like you're setting up lines of code like this:

```
for list_item in head_of_list:
```

Which makes no sense. In this case I think you could just `def` a simple generator:

```
 def iterate_from(list_item):
     while list_item is not None:
         yield list_item
         list_item = list_item.next
```

Which allows you to write code like this:

```
for list_item in iterate_from(head_of_list):
```